# How to save a table from table1 package into a CSV file

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to save tables developed with the package table1 into an excel file or into a picture.

In the [website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/furniture/vignettes/Table1.html) it is mentioned that "The table can be exported to a CSV with export = "file_name"" but when I try to do so, nothing is saved.

I have also noticed someone posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715760/webshot-does-not-save-viewer-table1) asking on how to save this table as an image but there was no reply.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The website you linked to is for the `furniture` package, which does have option to export to CSV. The `table1` package does not.

Comment: prefer `tableone`, which has a `print` option that return a table, that you can save with `write.csv`

Answer (score 2):

The `table1` package has the `as.data.frame(x)` function.
So once you have your table1 output how you want it, define it as an object.

```
    `dat <- expand.grid(id=1:10, sex=c("Male", "Female"), treat=c("Treated", "Placebo"))
dat$age <- runif(nrow(dat), 10, 50)
dat$age[3] <- NA  # Add a missing value
dat$wt <- exp(rnorm(nrow(dat), log(70), 0.2))

label(dat$sex) <- "Sex"
label(dat$age) <- "Age"
label(dat$treat) <- "Treatment Group"
label(dat$wt) <- "Weight"

units(dat$age) <- "years"
units(dat$wt) <- "kg"

# basic table 1
tab1_html<- table1(~ sex + age + wt | treat, data=dat)
tab1_df <- as.data.frame(tab1html)`
```

Which before you would give you:

[image: Normal Table1 output]

And now should give you

[image: data frame version of table1]